# I have a txt file and I want to make an array

Tags: python, arrays

I have a txt file written like this:([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSLAm.png))

```
1 !
2 "
3 #
4 $
5 %
```

and I want to make an array that would be like this

```
array = {'!':1,'"':2,'#':3,}

with open("Vaja2bTabela.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content]
```

and this is what I get:

```
['1 !', '2 "', '3 #', '4 $', '5 %',..]
```

Comment: For what it's worth your "array" is actually a dictionary

Comment: The output u need is not a array instead it's a dict, and u will need a dict comprehension to do tat.